# Yocto add driver from newer kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, yocto

I need to add a wireless driver to a Yocto image that uses kernel 3.10.17. My problem is that the driver entered mainline kernel since version 3.11 (and it is also part of the [backports](http://drvbp1.linux-foundation.org/~mcgrof/rel-html/backports/) project). I have read the [Yocto documentation](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6.1/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html) about kernel development, but it more confused me. What is the proper way to accomplish this? (I suppose adding the driver sources by hand is not).

Answer (score 0):

First: It's not clear which Yocto version you are using. So you might want to update to the current 1.7 version (Dizzy) which provides Kernel 3.10, 3.14 and 3.17.

You can find the kernel configuration in meta/recipes-kernel/linux. Be aware that a BSP or any other layer can also provide other kernel versions/configuration as well as limiting accepted/working version (especially if you use a BSP).

That said, you can define the kernel version that should be used by adding/adjusting PREFERRED_VERSION. An example is `PREFERRED_VERSION_linux-stable = "3.10"`. Another one you can find is `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/kernel = "linux-yocto-dev"`.

Please be aware that just choosing another kernel doesn't guarantee that the kernel module you want to have will be automatically build. You might need to adjust the kernel configuration to compile it into the kernel or build it as module.

Comment: It's Dizzy. I know how to configure the kernel, the problem here is that the kernel available to me, 3.10, does not contain the module I'm trying to deploy.

Comment: Did you ever try to install another kernel version like described in my answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am restricted to using this specific version.

Comment: If you cant use another kernel version (and don't find any other recipes without the backports) I do not see any other option as patching the kernel yourself or adjusting the kernel recipe to use the backports as source. Didn't see anything like that on http://layers.openembedded.org, too